# What is the jazz genre of the pianist Art Tatum?

Tags: jazz, identify-this-genre

What is [Art Tatum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_Tatum)'s style? His music sound quite different than Swing. How can you categorize his style?

Also, later in his life, was he involved in the Bebop scene? If so, what recordings/albums are there of Art doing bebop?

Answer (score 4):

Art Tatum is primarily known as a **Jazz artist.**

> As bebop began to take control of jazz in the early 1950s, Tatum
>   continued playing variations of the stride piano style, mostly at
>   small clubs throughout the country. In 1953, Tatum tracked a record
>   124 solos for noted producer Norman Granz and while the sessions were
>   hasty, they yielded material for 13 albums.
>
> These albums were recorded from 1953-1956 and are called ***The
>   Complete Pablo*** ***Solo Masterpieces***.  There are 8 volumes. 
>   These albums would be the closest recordings of bebop style by Art
>   Tatum.

http://www.biography.com/people/art-tatum-9502561

Comment: The term "stride piano" explains one element of his style.

Comment: @WheatWilliams agreed. I just always thought his main style was jazz.  He is always referred to as a jazz musician.